# Incorrect gerber rout output in Altium

Tags: altium, gerber, panel

I tried to get a panelized PCB from Altium using the embedded array option from the PCB Doc file. But, I get a continuous board edge around each of the PCB replicas: it would actually need mouse bites or tab routes or V scores. So, I imported the Gerber and drill files into Camtastic and deleted the board edges. I tried exporting the edited board edge file but gives me jagged lines all over. What should I do? [image: Altium Camtastic gerber export error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Header for Altium Camtastic Rout export]

Use the header given in the image and copy it to the top of the new board edge file before reloading it.